# Почему дерево разворачивается (IsExpanded) только до первого уровня?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Дерево должно полностью развернуться но разворачивается только первый уровень.

```
ExpandRecursively2(tw_tree, true);

private static void ExpandRecursively2(ItemsControl itemsControl, bool expand)
        {
            ItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator;
            for (int i = itemsControl.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                TreeViewItem treeViewItem = itemsControl as TreeViewItem;
                if (treeViewItem != null)
                    treeViewItem.IsExpanded = expand;
                //
                ItemsControl childControl = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ItemsControl;
                if (childControl != null) ExpandRecursively2(childControl, expand);
            }

        }
```

При этом странное поведение.

Если добавить в меню `ExpandRecursively2(tw_tree, true);` и нажимать много раз.

То каждый раз раскрывается следующая более глубокая ветка.

Здесь **childControl иногда равен 0**. Из-за этого на следующую ветку не идёт.

Почему он может быть равен 0. Что не так?

```
 ItemsControl childControl = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ItemsControl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902630/how-to-expand-all-nodes-of-a-wpf-treeview-in-code-behind#1902630

```
 <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
 </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже был в английской версии стака -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834081/wpf-treeview-where-is-the-expandall-method)

```
private void ExpandAll(ItemsControl items, bool expand)
    {
        foreach (object obj in items.Items)
        {
            ItemsControl childControl = items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as ItemsControl;
            if (childControl != null)
            {
                ExpandAll(childControl, expand);
            }
            TreeViewItem item = childControl as TreeViewItem;
            if (item != null)
                item.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }


    private void btnExpandAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (object item in this.myTV.Items)
        {
            TreeViewItem treeItem = this.myTV.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;
            if (treeItem != null)
                ExpandAll(treeItem, true);
            treeItem.IsExpanded = true;
        }
    }
```

UPD: Так должно работать

```
private void ExpandAll(TreeViewItem items, bool expand)
        {
            foreach (TreeViewItem obj in items.Items)
            {
                if (obj.Items != null &&
                    obj.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    ExpandAll(obj, expand);
                }
                items.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }


        private void btnExpandAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (TreeViewItem item in this.testTreeView.Items)
            {
                ExpandAll(item, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Это ничего не изменило. Все разные варианты ведут себя одинаково.

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: У меня в `in items.Items)` лежат объекты типа Node (мой класс)

Comment: Если у вас изменен treeviewitem это не меняет самого принципа работы, если принцип меняется то, тут уже нужно смотреть на реализацию `Node`. PS в wpf обычно подобные вещи делаются во ViewModel где и происходит 'открытие' и 'закрытие' элементов, а в xaml настраивается стиль дерева.

Comment: У меня иногда `childControl  = 0` почему он может быть равен 0 ?